# Copy data from a pointer or chain of pointers (Object pointer, templates) 

Tags: c++, templates, vector, copy-constructor

**How the `push_back` of `stl::vector` is implemented so it can make copy of any datatype .. may be pointer, double pointer and so on ...**

I'm implementing a template class having a function `push_back` almost similar to vector. Within this method a copy of argument should be inserted in internal allocated memory.

In case the argument is a pointer or a chain of pointers (an object pointer); the copy should be made of actual data pointed. *[updated as per comment]*

Can you pls tell how to create copy from pointer. so that if i delete the pointer in caller still the copy exists in my template class?

Code base is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        void push_back(const T& val_in)
        {
            T a (val_in); // It copies pointer, NOT data.
            m_pData[SIZE++] = a; 
        }
}
```

`Caller:`

```
// Initialize my custom Vector class.
Vector<MyClass*> v(3);

MyClass* a = new MyClass();
a->a = 0;
a->b = .5;

// push MyClass object pointer
// now push_back method should create a copy of data 
// pointed by 'a' and insert it to internal allocated memory.
// 'a' can be a chain of pointers also.

// how to achieve this functionality?
v.push_back(a);

delete a;
```

**I can simply use STL vector to accomplish the tasks but for experiment purposes i'm writing a template class which does exactly the same.**

Thanks.

Comment: First, your question is very vague and ambiguous. Your "argument is a pointer", but you want to insert "a copy of argument". That sounds like you simply want to copy the *pointer*, not the object it points to. Your first code snippet hopefully doesn't even compile either, and as such, it's hard to guess what it actually was you intended it to do. Lastly, your code is generally awful. Don't use `new` all over the place. That makes all the warning bells go off in my head. You're (ab)using C++ as if it were Java or C# (or as if you've read a few online tutorials)

Comment: Yes, that's right. probably i'm abusing C++ and i'm not cery clear with copy, pointer, reference .. etc. that's why i asked it here so that i can correct these things.

Comment: You should work a little harder on the question. Make the requirements clear, currently it is not clear whether the argument to `push_back` should be a pointer or whether the pointers are an internal detail (i.e. *internal allocated memory*: is it a single allocation for all contained objects, or a separate allocation per object). As a matter of fact, you should start explaining what are the requirements you have that are not met by the standard libraries, so that it is clear what you need.

Comment: @David: I want to create a template class having a `push_back` function similar to STL vector. I'll update the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

if you have polymorphic object ( the pointed object may be more specialized than the variable ), I suggest you creating a virtual method called clone() that allocate a new pointer with a copy of your object:

```
Base* A::clone() {
    A* toReturn = new A();
    //copy stuff
    return toReturn;
}
```

If you can't modify your Base class, you can use RTTI, but I will not approach this solution in this answer. ( If you want more details in this solution, please make a question regarding polymorphic cloning with RTTI).

If you have not a polymorphic object, you may allocate a new object by calling the copy constructor.

```
void YourVector::push_back(Base* obj) {
    Base* copy = new Base(obj);
}
```

But it smells that what you are really needing is shared_ptr, avaliable in `<tr1/memory>` ( or `<memory>` if you use C++0x ).

## Update based on comments

You may also have a two template parameters list:

```
template <typename T>
struct CopyConstructorCloner {
    T* operator()(const T& t) {
        return new T(t);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename CLONER=CopyConstructorCloner<T> >
class MyList {
    CLONER cloneObj;
public:
    // ...
    void push_back(const T& t) {
        T* newElement = cloneObj(t);
        // save newElemenet somewhere, dont forget to delete it later
    }
}
```

With this approach it is possible to define new cloning politics for things like pointers.

Still, I recommend you to use shared_ptrs.

Comment: The caller can be anyone and can't be forced to provide a clone method. and if i use templates, last line in code will look like `T copy = new T*(obj)` ... and compiler doesn't accept it.

Comment: In STL, when you have - for example - vector<MyClass>, the vector copies the given object in push_back, and if it is a pointer, the pointer is copied and the caller must guarantee that the pointer will remain valid.

In your case, it may be a nice idea to have different implementations for pointer based, and for reference based vectors.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a copy construction:

```
MyClass *p = new MyClass();
MyVector<MyClass*> v;
v.push_back(new MyClass(*p));
```

**Update**: From you updated question, you can definitely override `push_back`

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector {
public:
  void push_back (T obj); // general push_back
  template<typename TYPE>  // T can already be a pointer, so declare TYPE again
  void push_back (TYPE *pFrom)
  {
    TYPE *pNew = new TYPE(*pFrom);
    // use pNew in your logic...
  }
};
```

Comment: The passed argument may be used by caller after pushing to vector. I should not change that.

Comment: Pls see the upated question. that's why simple copy construction can't be used.

Comment: but that's still not a generic one, I guess. `MyVector<MyClass**> v;` and push_back is called with `&p`

Comment: @iammilind: Why are you receiving the argument as a reference? That does not make sense, the argument to `push_back` should either be a `const&` (generic case) or a copy (particular case if you want an overload for pointers), but a non-const reference does not make sense.

Comment: @David, I have edited my answer. The idea here is to have a seperate `push_back` for pointer to copy them. This is just a demo for the idea. Still it's not the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this kind of problems it is better to use smart pointers ex: boost::shared_ptr or any other equivalent implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
    T*     data;          // Pointer to internal memory
    size_t count;         // Number of items of T stored in data
    size_t allocated;     // Total space that is available in data
                          // (available space is => allocated - count)

    void push_back(std::auto_ptr<T> item) // Use auto pointer to indicate transfer of ownership
    /*void push_back(T* item) The dangerous version of the interface */
    {
        if ((allocated - count) == 0)
        {    reallocateSomeMemory();
        }

        T*   dest = &data[count];  // location to store item

        new (dest) T(*item);       // Use placement new and copy constructor.
        ++count;
    }

    // All the other stuff you will need.
};
```

#### Edit based on comments:

To call it you need to do this:

```
MyVector<Plop>    data;

std::auto_ptr<Plop>   item(new Plop());   // ALWAYS put dynamically allocated objects
                                          // into a smart pointer. Not doing this is bad
                                          // practice.
data.push_back(item);
```

I use auto_ptr because RAW pointers are bad (ie in real C++ code (unlike C) you rarely see pointers, they are hidden inside smart pointers).

Comment: Error in caller module: error C2664: 'Vector<T>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MyClass *' to 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>'

Comment: if i change the signature to `void push_back(const T& item)` ... it's not copied.

Comment: @Azodious: Look at the edit. You need to read about smart pointers.

Comment: but in this way caller is compelled to use Smart Pointer. can this be avoided? and Yes. i've to read more.

Comment: @Martin: I think this changes the semantics in ways that it was not intended. In particular it *steals* ownership of the original object, forcing the transfer of ownership.

Comment: @David Rodríguez: The questoon explicitly says he is going to delete it.

Comment: @Azodious: Yes. Change `std::auto_ptr<T>` into `T*`. But the whole point is to compell users to do the correct thing. Otherwise their code will suck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `new` for the given datatype `T`. The `push_back` implementation should (must) call the copy-constructor or the assignment operator. The memory should have been allocated to hold those elemnets that are being pushed. The intial memory allocation should not call CTOR of type T. Something like:

```
   T* pArray; 
   pArray = (T*) new  BYTE[sizeof(T) * INITIAL_SIZE);
```

And then just put new object into pArray, calling the assignment operator.